# S3 uploading high disk I/O and CPU usage

Tags: aws-sdk-go

I faced hight CPU and I/O usage when I tried to upload 100Gb of small files (PNG images) to S3 bucket via very simple [go s3 uploader](https://github.com/wodby/go-aws-s3/blob/master/main.go).

Is there any way to limit bandwidth (i.e. via aws-sdk-go config) or something else to make the process of uploading less intensive or effective :) to reduce CPU and I/O usage.

I've tried nice CPU and IO but it actually doesn't help.

Comment: Doesn't look like a programming question to me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried S3Manager, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/s3manager/? From the docs:

Package s3manager provides utilities to upload and download objects from S3 concurrently. Helpful for when working with large objects.

Comment: Aha, it's interesting, I'll try.